# Is there a non-covariant `Type[T]`?

Tags: python, higher-order-functions, python-typing, typing, invariance

Suppose I'm trying to write type hints for a library function that registers a deserializer for a user-defined type: the user should provide a type `T` along with a function `decode: str -> T`.

The most natural way I can think to write this with python's PEP-484 type hints is the following:

```py
from typing import Callable, Type, TypeVar
T = TypeVar("T")
def register_decoder(type_: Type[T], decode: Callable[[str], T]):
    ...
```

Unfortunately for me, the fact that `Type[T]` is covariant in `T` means this is not quite strict enough on the decode function: at least in pyright, the invocation `register_decoder(int, decode=str)` passes typecheck, with the type variable `T` resolved as the union `int | str`:

[image: pyright's inference of int|str]

Is there a way to type-hint this method that enforces the constraint that `decode` returns instances of `type_`, so that this example raises an error because `str` does not return `int`? One thing that would do the job is a non-covariant equivalent of `Type[T]` that accepts only the *exact* class object `T` rather than any subtype, but I'm not sure anything like this exists in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Using `mypy --strict` gives me the expected error. Must be something specific to the linter you are using.

```
from typing import Callable, Type, TypeVar
T = TypeVar("T")
def register_decoder(type_: Type[T], decode: Callable[[str], T]) -> None:
    return

register_decoder(int, str)
```

```
>mypy --strict test.py
test.py:6: error: Argument 2 to "register_decoder" has incompatible type "Type[str]"; expected "Callable[[str], int]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

>python --version
Python 3.9.5

>mypy --version
mypy 0.910
```

Comment: Very interesting! I hadn't thought to try mypy - I've just been using pyright, and after delving into the documentation for `Type[]` I figured the issue was with my type hint, not the type checker. From my limited understanding I still feel like this is the case - isn't pyright's interpretation with `T = int|str` actually completely valid given that `Type[T]` is covariant in `T`?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis this is a good question, and to be honest I'm not sure. My guess would be that mypy does not automatically consider unions unless specified, and prefers types with contravariance. This more verbose example would work `a: Union[Type[str], Type[int]] = int; register_decoder(a, str)`

Comment: This is due to mypy's preference for "join" and "meet" operations over unions (https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Type-Checker#join-and-meet). This preference is a source of many, many bugs in mypy, so pyright's preference for unions is usually desirable (https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12056). I would say that mypy gives a desirable type error by accident here, rather than this being a feature of mypy's type-variable solver.